# checkbox - list elements

Tags: java, checkbox, struts2

my checkbox is not showing the values of my list as "checkable" things.
Its just saying "publication.keywords" :( 
But my list is not empty, as I can show it in an iterator.

Please help me. Whats my mistake?

This is my Checkbox

```
<s:checkbox key="publication.keyword" list="keywords.{name}" />
```

Its working with the Iterator

```
<s:iterator value="keywords">
<tr>
<td><s:property value="name" /><br></td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Don't you mean [`s:checkboxlist`](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-scheckboxlist-multiple-check-boxes-example/)?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is wrong.

Looking at your iterator, the checkboxlist should be like :

```
<s:checkboxlist list="keywords"  listValue="name" listKey="name"/>
```

The 'listKey' attribute specifies what will be submitted, if that checkbox is checked. I have used `name` for now, you can change it to what you require at the backend.

For e.g. if

```
List<MyBean> keywords
```

and

```
class MyBean
{
String name;
Integer id;
//getters and setters
}
```

then, the `s:checkbox` can be something like :

```
<s:checkboxlist list="keywords"  listValue="name" listKey="id"/>
```